# Symfony Doctrine Mapping - Different entity and property names in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony5

I have issue with updating entities with console command bin/console doctrine:mapping:import. Project requirements forces different names for class names and properties in code and in database, for example:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_db")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_user", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="user_id_user_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
    */
    private $email;
}
```

Database schema will be updated many times during project development. After running doctrine:mapping:import again instead of mapping user_db table to User entity (because annotation points to this table) this command creates new entity UserDB. After every database change I'm forced to manually compare changes and add them to code. Is there any way to update mapping for those entities (change column details, add new columns, remove removed)?

I'm using Symfony 5.4 as it is LTS version currently.

Comment: i don't understand your question clearly. So why can't you rely on the annotation mappings and every time you change them you do a doctrine:schema:update then doctrine:migrations:diff and thus you got your DB updated accordingly and you have the migration script to go back and forth ?

Comment: @medunes Database is created by other team, I'm just getting new sql files that creates entire database every time when something has changed. I'm not using migrations in this project. Original database is in different language than English, that's why I have different entities names than tables and property different than columns in database

Comment: i don't see an out-of-the-box generic solution here.
Maybe try spotting some re-occuring patterns and run a dedicated mapper/generator..